# JqGrid error when connecting to Mysql on Windows 10,but in 7 it's fine

Tags: mysql, json, xml, jqgrid

I got problem running this code on Windows 10, but when I run it on another PC with Windows 7, it runs fine.

This is the markup for the grid:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>Your page title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#grid").jqGrid({
                colModel: [
                    { name: "kd_cabang"         ,label:"Kode Cabang" },
                    { name: "jmlh_gardu"        ,label:"Jumlah Gardu"},
                    { name: "jmlh_gardu_ctrler" ,label:"Jumlah Gardu Controller"},
                    { name: "lat"               ,label:"Latitude"},
                    { name: "lng"                ,label:"Longtitude"}
                ],

            datatype : "json",
            url:"tabel_gardu_pln_query.php"
            });
        });
        //]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="grid"></table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and for the query code (tabel_gardu_pln_query.php)

```
<?php 
require_once ('koneksi2.php' ) ;


$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tabel_cabang ");
if ($db->error) {
   die('Query Error : '.$db->errno.' - '.$db->error);
}

$responce = (object)[];
$responce->total = 1;
$responce->page = 1;
$responce->records = 1;

$i=0;

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row['Kd_Cabang'];
    $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array(
        $row['Kd_Cabang'],
        $row['Jmlh_Gardu'],
        $row['Jmlh_Gardu_Ctrler'],
        $row['Lat'],
        $row['Lng']     

    );
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($responce);
?>
```

For the koneksi2.php code is

```
<?php
$hostname  = "localhost";
$username  = "root";
$password  = "";
$dbname  = "gardu_pln";

$db = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, 
$dbname);

if ($db->connect_errno) {
    die('Koneksi Error: '.$db->connect_errno.' - '. 
    $db->connect_error);
}

//  session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION ['ses_id_comp'] )){ 
    $ses_id_comp='1';   
}
?>
```

and when i run it, it's shows this[this is when i'm using xml type (code not included)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z41l7.jpg)
and when using datatype json this happen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaP9L.jpg)

BTW, sorry if I don't give enough detail, I just started coding like 2-3 months ago only

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should describe the problems that you are talking about.

Comment: _"I got problem running this code in windows 10"_, what is the problem? Do you get any errors? If yes, please share them.

Comment: You write about "JqGrid error". It would be helpful if you would include the exact error description or the screenshot. Additionally it would be better if you include test JSON data, which returns your server instead of PHP code. You can open Developer Tools in web browser, click on Network tab to see HTTP traffic. One will be able to use the JSON response for reproducing the problem without having any server and Mysql DB.